# Display all null mysql values as N/A

Tags: php, mysql, null

I'm working on a clients website and they want a simple check in page for their overnight employees.  Each employee can fill out up to 6 clients names on a form.  The data entered on the form is then stored in a database.  The data is then displayed on an admin page so that it can be checked to make sure each employee checks in.  The issue I am having is that I want all null values to display as N/A or --, I haven't decided.  I know I have to have a loop but I'm not sure how to read the null values.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would the below answers work if I had up to 14 null values per row?  Not to mention that there would be up to 120 rows?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.  I have decided to set the null values to N/A when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend storing N/A in the database on the form submit. If using php

```
If (Isset($var)!=true){
$var="N/a";

}

Insert $var into database
```

Comment: I like this answer the best.  I will check if the input is null a when the form is submitted.  I'm not the best at MySQL and would probably mess up my script is I went playing around.

Comment: This is essentially forcing behaviour onto the database engine. NULL is a perfectly valid value in a lot of circumstances. Say for example (although unlikely) you had a customer called N/A how would you tell the difference between a genuine customer and a value that has been entered to signify that there is no data.

Comment: @Peter: agreed.  In the future, the person responsible for troubleshooting issues or supporting the database must then be aware that NULL has absolutely no meaning in context of this particular database, nor fundamentally do strings for that matter if going down this proposed route.

Comment: While I agree and completely understand the use of COALESCE I recommended the above solution for simplicity. Also when working with large databases COALESCE has been proven to increase processor load.

Comment: @Ray Hughes: whether `COALESCE` should be used instead is debatable.  There are actually several solutions.  However, without knowing the exact requirements of the database itself now and in the future in OP's case, I agree it would not be fare to automatically discount your solution.  So, I take back what I said.

Answer (score 4):

You could in your `select` statement, do `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(field, 'N/A') FROM Table
```

Answer (score 4):

You have not mentioned fully if you wish for the database data to be in tact and only the data to be modified for output.

If you only want the output modified you could do :-

```
SELECT field1, field2, COALESCE(field3,'N/A')
FROM tableName;
```

In this example if field3 is null it will replace it in the returned data to be N/A otherwise it will be left as is.

Answer (score 1):

Use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) or [ISNULL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

```
SELECT COALESCE(FieldName, 'N/A')
```

or

```
SELECT  ISNULL(FieldName, 'N/A')
```